# Unusual wordpress error

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

vti_encoding:SR|utf8-nl vti_timelastmodified:TR|09 Jul 2013 16:24:35 -0000 vti_extenderversion:SR|5.0.2.6819 vti_lineageid:SR|{33CCFEAB-D114-4C7D-B37F-74F44C36A405} vti_cacheddtm:TX|09 Jul 2013 16:24:35 -0000 vti_filesize:IR|4470 vti_backlinkinfo:VX| vti_encoding:SR|utf8-nl vti_timelastmodified:TR|09 Jul 2013 16:24:36 -0000 vti_extenderversion:SR|5.0.2.6819 vti_lineageid:SR|{8E686066-5BE2-4202-8734-82D33B6200AE} vti_cacheddtm:TX|09 Jul 2013 16:24:36 -0000 vti_filesize:IR|57 vti_backlinkinfo:VX| vti_encoding:SR|utf8-nl vti_timelastmodified:TR|09 Jul 2013 16:24:34 -0000 vti_extenderversion:SR|5.0.2.6819 vti_lineageid:SR|{4BE27726-2898-4FB4-8328-8D1F9DE92308} vti_cacheddtm:TX|09 Jul 2013 16:24:34 -0000 vti_filesize:IR|61 vti_backlinkinfo:VX| vti_encoding:SR|utf8-nl vti_timelastmodified:TR|09 Jul 2013 16:24:38 -0000 vti_extenderversion:SR|5.0.2.6819 vti_lineageid:SR|{BF6492D3-CEFE-41BF-A8C1-AE9D3AF96227} vti_cacheddtm:TX|09 Jul 2013 16:24:38 -0000 vti_filesize:IR|55 vti_backlinkinfo:VX| vti_encoding:SR|utf8-nl vti_timelastmodified:TR|09 Jul 2013 16:24:37 -0000 vti_extenderversion:SR|5.0.2.6819 vti_lineageid:SR|{0790A047-25D8-4E9E-BD2B-008773938F41} vti_cacheddtm:TX|09 Jul 2013 16:24:37 -0000 vti_filesize:IR|2320 vti_backlinkinfo:VX| vti_encoding:SR|utf8-nl vti_timelastmodified:TR|09 Jul 2013 16:04:26 -0000 vti_extenderversion:SR|5.0.2.6819 vti_lineageid:SR|{92663116-3805-46ED-BFDA-E3A61B9AF724} vti_cacheddtm:TX|09 Jul 2013 16:04:26 -0000 vti_filesize:IR|2787 vti_backlinkinfo:VX| vti_encoding:SR|utf8-nl vti_timelastmodified:TR|09 Jul 2013 16:24:36 -0000 vti_extenderversion:SR|5.0.2.6819 vti_lineageid:SR|{8731AE64-FCE6-40DA-A278-F9B478BFE890} vti_cacheddtm:TX|09 Jul 2013 16:24:36 -0000 vti_filesize:IR|57 vti_backlinkinfo:VX|

My WordPress site since yesterday has been showing this unusual error message. Help please I didn't change anything so I am really lost as to the reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme editor is accessing files in the '_vti_cnf' folder that is inside your theme folder. Delete the '_vti_cnf' folder, log out of WordPress, then log back in. The theme editor should now display the proper files.

Here is [another solution](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-edit-theme-pages-in-wordpress-281?replies=8) on the Wordpress forums.